# Access props inside a closure

Tags: reactjs, react-native

calling `this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);` inside `componentWillMount()` works fine for me, but if I try this code

```
componentWillMount(){
    Keychain
    .getGenericPassword()
    .then(function(credentials) {
         this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
    })
}
```

I get an error telling me that this.props.navigation is undefined. I suppose that the problem is that I am calling it inside .then. Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: context issue, use this: `.then((credentials) => {`

Answer (score 0):

you just change the scope of this

try this

```
componentWillMount(){
Keychain
  .getGenericPassword()
  .then((credentials)=>{
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
});
```

or else use extra val for this like

```
var _self = this;
```